# How to properly use exception handling iwth modal dialogs?

Tags: c++, winapi, exception, modal-dialog

I have some ambiguity on handling exceptions: Why I was recommended not to throw from a Dialog Box?

Here is my try:

In `wndproc` something like this:

```
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(LOWORD(wparam)){
            case IDD_ABOUT:{
                try{
                    int ret = DialogBox(GetModuleHandle(NULL),MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUT), hwnd, AboutDlgProc);
                    if(ret == IDOK)
                        MessageBox(hwnd, "Dialog exited with IDOK.", "Notice",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                    else
                        if(ret == IDCANCEL)
                            MessageBox(hwnd, "Dialog exited with IDCANCEL.", "Notice",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                    else 
                    if(ret == -1)
                        MessageBox(hwnd, "Dialog failed!", "Error",MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                }
                catch(char *pError){
                    MessageBox(NULL,pError,"Error",MB_OK);
                //  EndDialog(hwnd, IDOK);
                }
                catch(...){
                    MessageBox(NULL,"Something went wrong!","Error",MB_OK);
                //  EndDialog(hwnd, IDOK);
                }
            }
        break;
        case ID_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    }
    break;
```

And in my modal Dialog procedure I throw if If bad input when clicking button get Input:

```
// In AboutDlgProc:

//...
case IDOK:
    GetInputFromEditBox; // creating buffer and reading text and blahblah
    if(not_good_input)
        throw "Bad input"; //
```

I know to use more powerful handling is to use the hierarchies and inheriting from `std::exception`... But here only for practice.

- Is this is how should I throw? Or should I do it other way? Should un-comment lines above?  `//   EndDialog(hwnd, IDOK);`?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code looks ok.  You were probably recommended not to throw from the Dialog Box procedure because you must NOT let any exceptions exit from your code back into the MS-Windows code which called your wndproc.  The MS-Windows code is `C` and does not know what to do with C++ exceptions, stack unwinding etc.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Thank you. Would you  mind to add an answer?

Comment: @RichardCritten: But Richard I think I throw from from my dialog box procedure? `throw "Bad input";`?

Comment: This tends to end poorly on 32-bit code that runs in the wow64 emulator on the 64-bit version of Windows.  Unwinding the stack through the 64-bit window manager, from 32-bit to 64-bit back to 32-bit, is a problem they did not know how to solve correctly.  Worse case outcome is on Win7, the exception completely disappears.  Later versions re-raise an SEH exception.  It is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573(v=vs.85).aspx) but nobody knows what it means.  It means "don't do it".

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Richard's comment about stack unwinding there is an even more fundamental issue in that DialogBox creates an HWND and deactivates the parent window, if you throw an exception the created HWND won't get destroyed and the parent won't get re-enabled.

Comment: plus 1. Add an example.